# Spring Boot 3 micrometer trace and span IDs not propagating outside controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

We're moving from Spring Boot 2.x and Spring Cloud Sleuth to Spring Boot 3.x and Micrometer tracing. We're only interested in the trace and span IDs, and at least for the moment we're not interested in the observability.

Where Sleuth did tracing more or less out of the box, for some odd reason, the trace and span IDs aren't logged outside the `@RestController` when using Micrometer. The other components are in separate libraries, that take care of such things as logging all requests to RabbitMQ, setting up an OAuth2 resource server, etc. It's because of these libraries that I cannot provide a minimal example. And anyway, a minimal example works. It's the production code that doesn't.

There isn't any configuration taking place, other than the properties in the `application.yml` file, and its relevant content is as follows:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
  pattern:
    level: "%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]"
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0
    propagation:
      type: b3
  metrics:
    distribution:
      percentiles-histogram:
        greeting: true
        http:
          server:
            requests: true
```

I've written a small Spring Boot 2 service that does nothing other than pass all requests to the Spring Boot 3 service, using Sleuth. Its output is this (redacted a bit for anonymity):

```
2023-04-12 08:43:22.855 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] INFO LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-12 08:43:22.855 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] INFO LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-12 08:43:22.857 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] INFO LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet - Completed initialization in 2 ms
2023-04-12 08:43:22.874 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] INFO LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ny.company.utils.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter - UUID: [5457319f-7310-42de-a5a7-0230f8ffcf5c] - Received [HTTP/1.1] [GET] on URL [http://localhost:8080/productStock?sku=HLD007353] from physical IP [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] and XFF IP [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]. Content-Type [null] and Content-Length [-1].
2023-04-12 08:43:22.887 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] DEBUG LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /productStock?sku=HLD007353
2023-04-12 08:43:22.893 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] DEBUG LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-04-12 08:43:23.277 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] DEBUG LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider - Authenticated token
2023-04-12 08:43:23.280 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] DEBUG LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@b27352b4, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[SCOPE_profile email, ROLE_offline_access, ROLE_uma_authorization, ROLE_default-roles-phoenix, ROLE_role_stock:read, ROLE_manage-account, ROLE_view-profile, ROLE_manage-account-links]]
2023-04-12 08:43:23.293 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] DEBUG LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor - Authorized filter invocation [GET /productStock?sku=HLD007353] with attributes [permitAll]
2023-04-12 08:43:23.294 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] DEBUG LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain - Secured GET /productStock?sku=HLD007353
2023-04-12 08:43:24.524 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] DEBUG LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-04-12 08:43:24.533 [test-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,] INFO LNVPF1B8UCP [http-nio-8080-exec-1] my.company.utils.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter - UUID: [5457319f-7310-42de-a5a7-0230f8ffcf5c] - HTTP Request complete. Response with status code [200], Content-Type [application/json] and Content-Length [2197].
```

So the trace ID and span ID are displayed correctly. However, they are missing in all parts of the Spring Boot 3 service:

```
2023-04-12T08:43:24.258+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : ---- FILTER ----
2023-04-12T08:43:24.258+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : accept-encoding: gzip
2023-04-12T08:43:24.258+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : user-agent: ReactorNetty/1.0.18
2023-04-12T08:43:24.258+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : host: localhost:8081
2023-04-12T08:43:24.259+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : accept: */*
2023-04-12T08:43:24.259+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : authorization: Bearer (redacted)
2023-04-12T08:43:24.259+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : x-b3-traceid: 6c93335d5b0e4a9c
2023-04-12T08:43:24.259+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : x-b3-spanid: 253051e75ac78374
2023-04-12T08:43:24.259+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : x-b3-parentspanid: 6c93335d5b0e4a9c
2023-04-12T08:43:24.259+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : x-b3-sampled: 0
2023-04-12T08:43:24.259+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : traceparent: 00-00000000000000006c93335d5b0e4a9c-253051e75ac78374-00
2023-04-12T08:43:24.260+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : Received [HTTP/1.1] [GET] on URL [http://localhost:8081/productStock?sku=HLD007353] from physical IP [127.0.0.1] and XFF IP [127.0.0.1]. Content-Type [null] and Content-Length [-1].
2023-04-12T08:43:24.334+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,eece83b9a11ddd20] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.stock.web.StockManagementController  : Received request: SKU=HLD007353, serial=null, channel=null
2023-04-12T08:43:24.354+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,eece83b9a11ddd20] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.stock.web.StockManagementController  : Returned 4 result(s):
2023-04-12T08:43:24.354+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,eece83b9a11ddd20] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.stock.web.StockManagementController  :   Product=Samsung Galaxy A40 DS Black, serial=354878110668408, price=249.0
2023-04-12T08:43:24.354+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,eece83b9a11ddd20] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.stock.web.StockManagementController  :   Product=Samsung Galaxy A40 DS Black, serial=354878110139996, price=249.0
2023-04-12T08:43:24.354+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,eece83b9a11ddd20] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.stock.web.StockManagementController  :   Product=Samsung Galaxy A40 DS Black, serial=354878110674786, price=249.0
2023-04-12T08:43:24.355+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,6c93335d5b0e4a9c,eece83b9a11ddd20] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.stock.web.StockManagementController  :   Product=Samsung Galaxy A40 DS Black, serial=354878110674893, price=249.0
2023-04-12T08:43:24.359+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.u.springrest.filters.LoggingFilter   : HTTP Request complete. Response with status code [200], Content-Type [application/json] and Content-Length [1757].
2023-04-12T08:43:24.360+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.s.a.l.services.SecurityAuditService  : Sending security Audit Message to exchange [vf.iss.appsec.x] and routing key [vf.iss.appsec.q].
2023-04-12T08:43:24.362+02:00  WARN [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.s.a.l.services.SecurityAuditService  : Trace ID is empty
2023-04-12T08:43:24.366+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.s.a.l.services.SecurityAuditService  : Audit message (security) sent.
2023-04-12T08:43:24.366+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.s.a.l.services.SecurityAuditService  : Req or Resp body object is null. Not applying filters.
2023-04-12T08:43:24.369+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.s.a.l.services.SecurityAuditService  : Sending verbose Audit Message to exchange [mt.vf.audit.app.x] and routing key [mt.vf.audit.app.q].
2023-04-12T08:43:24.369+02:00  INFO [stock-management-service,,] 19504 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] m.c.s.a.l.services.SecurityAuditService  : Audit message (verbose) sent.
```

Please note that the `LoggingFilter` class happily prints the HTTP B3 tracing headers; however, Spring does not log the trace and span IDs. It's also not a thread issue, because everything happens in the same thread.

We're reverting back to Spring Boot 2 and Sleuth for now, because having the trace and span IDs is essential. But if anybody could shed some light onto what might be happening, that'd be appreciated.

Edit: after a lot more debugging, it turns out that the `ThreadLocal` holds holds a `TraceContext` that is null. It still doesn't solve my problem, though.

Comment: do u use webflux?

Comment: No, it's a very simple REST controller using Spring Web. It just fetches data from a database. The bewildering thing is that, now I've moved it to Spring Boot 2.7.x using the same BOM that another service using (which does use WebFlux, but as a client) it complains about missing services. Which is probably correct, those services are not in the `spring.factories` file, but then why does it work with every other service?

Answer (score 3):

Eventually I managed to solve this issue. The extra logging was taking place in a `Filter` that was annotated with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`. As a consequence, this filter ran before the `ServerHttpObservationFilter`, which is responsible for injecting the trace context.

The solution was to remove the `@Order` annotation, and adding `@AutoConfiguration(after = ServerHttpObservationFilter.class)` to ensure that the logging filter runs after the trace context has been made available.

Comment: Note that `@AutoConfiguration(after = ServerHttpObservationFilter.class)` does not order filters relatively but orders auto-configurations for precedence. The `ServerHttpObservationFilter` is not an auto-configuration class, so this has no effect. Removing the `@Order` from your custom filter sets it as "lowest precedence" and is enough to solve this issue.